# pass $q rejection to 404 page in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

Once I redirect how do I get the contents of the rejection to my 404's controller? What I'm trying to do is redirect to a 404 and then show the response from the server.

```
services.factory('errorInterceptor', ['$injector','$location', function ($injector, $location, $q, $state) {
return {
    'responseError': function (rejection) {
        $injector.get('$state').transitionTo('404');
        return $q.reject(rejection);

    }
  };
}]);

services.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('errorInterceptor');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the rejection as a parameter in transitionto

```
$injector.get('$state').transitionTo('404',rejection);
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statetransitiontoto-toparams--options

that rejection will be $stateParam in the 404 controller.